# Manual date selection in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to allow a manual date + time.  I have a worksheet that has a button for which when the user updates the table, they click the button and it inputs the current date and time.  The challenges is I currently have the Now() function and every time I open the workbook, the date gets updated based on the now date.  I want this to be a manual action.

I've searched here and on the internet, and all I can find is the automated NOW() or others that seem to automate the process.

Comment: Hi, please explicitly state your question, or at the very least define what you mean by "manual action".

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA to write the current date (plus time) into a cell on a button click:

```
Public Sub MyButton_Click()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Now

End Sub
```

Just link that procedure with a button and it will write the date+time into A1 every time you click the button.